# Remove trailing digits for a constant - Java

Tags: java

My fields are of constant length `4`. So, I need the output of the format:

```
Input  Output

1   -    0001

10   -   0010

999  -  0999

1111 -  1111

12345 - 1234
```

I used `String.format("%04d", inputValue);`

How to achieve the last one?

Comment: That depends on your requirements. The last entry would mean loss of information and you'd have to define how to deal with that. Rounding? Cut at the end or front?

Comment: what is your type of inputValue whether it is String or integer?

Comment: @santhosh It must be an integer type, since `"%04d"` is the conversion used at present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want the first four digits you could use

```
String.format("%04d", inputValue).substring(0, 4);
```

To get rid of the leading zeros you can use

```
private static String limitToSeven(final int num) {
    String str = String.format("%07d", num).replaceAll("^0+", "");
    return  str.length() <= 7 ? str : str.substring(0,7);
}
```

Comment: yes.. it works.. thanks.. i thought there would be some formatting specially for that..

Comment: I have another doubt. I need always 5 digit. The input length is 7. I need only the first 5 valid digits and in case it has preceding zeros, then, i have to leave the preceding zeros till the length is 5. What should I do? Eg: 0000111 --> 00111   1234567 -->12345